# Copy text from command line as formatted text

Tags: command-line, html

So I have a script that outputs this

```
<pre style="background:#f1f1f1;color:#000;font-weight:bold;">echo 'Hello World';</pre>
```

What I would like to do it copy it to the clipboard as rich text and not plain text.  Is this possible?

Right now I have this command:

```
create-codeblock | pbcopy
```

This obviously only copies the plain text html code to the clipboard.  What I really want is the html formatted version copied to the clipboard.  Any thoughts?

What I am trying to do in the end is paste rich formatted text into Evernote.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you? I think you want to use `textutil`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095497/how-can-i-generate-a-rich-text-link-for-pbcopy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As aglasser commented, you can use `textutil` like so:

```
create-codeblock | textutil -stdin -format html -convert rtf -stdout | pbcopy
```